Command to disable all tcolorboxes without deleting / commenting out them in source code?
I'm writing a text including multiple tcolorboxes. Now I need a version of the PDF without these boxes. Is there a command to switch off / disable all tcolorboxes? Of course I can comment out every single one.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext{}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=whatever]
  some text
\end{tcolorbox}

\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=nextone]
  here we go again.

  A second paragraph

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

I'm looking for something like \tcbset{hide-all} and all boxes are gone without a trace in the PDF.

As long as you have only explicit {tcolorbox} I guess \RenewDocumentEnvironment{tcolorbox}{ob}{}{} should work.

@campa Yes! Thank you. I reduced my MWE too much, though. I've got tcolorboxes with paragraphs and get an error: "Paragraph ended before \environment tcolorbox  was complete." I'll edit my question in a minute. But however, if this makes things messy, I'll swap all empty lines in tcolorboxes with \\.

Ah, well, if you have paragraphs it's as simple as using o+b instead of ob as argument specifier. My point was that this might not work if you "hide" a tcolorbox behind custom-defined environments, or \newtcolorbox.

Maybe have a look at the comment package

@campa No, I don't hide the a tcolorbox inside something. Your second solution works! Would you write a one line answer I'll happily accept?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz For future documents I'll think about something like \AddToHook{env/tcolorbox/before}{\begin{comment} and accordingly \end{comment}. Nice idea.

@KeksDose With the comment package, it would be even easier to have \excludecomment{tcolorbox} (possibly commenting out the \usepackage{tcolorbox}.

You can use \RenewDocumentEnvironment with the +b argument specifier to redefine {tcolorbox}. This seems to work also with environments defined by \newtcolorbox.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tcolorbox}{ o +b }{}{}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{mybox}
some text

some text
\end{mybox}

\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=nextone]
  here we go again.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


If you only use explicit {tcolorbox} environments then it would be more efficient to comment out \usepackage{tcolorbox} and use \NewDocumentEnvironment instead.
